# Having trouble when trying to md5 a string in android

Tags: android, networking, request, md5

On Android, I get the following error when I try to `md5` a string:

```
"Performing stop of activity that is not resumed"
```

I need to attach the `md5` to a URL.

Please help

//md5 code

MessageDigest digest;

```
    try {
        digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        digest.reset();
        digest.update(text.getBytes());
        byte[] a = digest.digest();
        int len = a.length;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len << 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            sb.append(Character.forDigit((a[i] & 0xf0) >> 4, 16));
            sb.append(Character.forDigit(a[i] & 0x0f, 16));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
```

//          e.printStackTrace();
        }

//request code
encryptedTaskId = MDConversion.MD5(taskId);

```
            Log.v("inside doInBackground :: ", "inside doInBackground :: ");
            totalUrl = baseUrl + "&access_token=" + accessToken + "&id=" + encryptedTaskId;

            Log.v("fetch users to forward task url :: ", "url :: "+totalUrl);

            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(totalUrl);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response;

            response = client.execute(get);
```

Comment: Would you show ur code ??

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this static function:

```
 public static final String md5(final String toEncrypt) {
    try {
        final MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");
        digest.update(toEncrypt.getBytes());
        final byte[] bytes = digest.digest();
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02X", bytes[i]));
        }
        return sb.toString().toLowerCase();
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        return ""; // Impossibru!
    }
}
```

Comment: I am already using this. my problem is that when i do this is get the above mentioned error. the execution stops at that line

Comment: Care to show us how are you calling the md5 function and attach it to the URL?

Comment: encryptedTaskId = MDConversion.MD5(taskId);

Comment: totalUrl = baseUrl + "&access_token=" + accessToken + "&id=" + encryptedTaskId;

Comment: totalUrl = baseUrl + "?access_token=" + accessToken + "&id=" + encryptedTaskId; –

Comment: this is what i do to md5 MessageDigest digest;

  try {
   digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
   digest.reset();
   digest.update(text.getBytes());
   byte[] a = digest.digest();
   int len = a.length;
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len << 1);
   for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    sb.append(Character.forDigit((a[i] & 0xf0) >> 4, 16));
    sb.append(Character.forDigit(a[i] & 0x0f, 16));
   }
   return sb.toString();
  } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
//   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return null;